# How to save user informations in application

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, user-input

I enter some user informations to my upp via textifields. I want my app to save these informations and whenever my app is opened, use the same informations. I used NSUserDefaults but if I clean the app from the RAM (mean, from the running processes) and tryto stat/open my app, it crashes. What do I have to use to save user informations all the time.

**EDIT**

I save my data in AppDelegate, I want when the user clicks home button, user infos be saved. Here is my code:

```
 - (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        NSLog(@"url in background: %@", mainUrl);
//uName and passwd are strings that come from other classes
        NSUserDefaults *name=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [name setObject:uName forKey:@"userNameDefault"];

        NSUserDefaults *passWd=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
        [passWd setObject:passwd forKey:@"passwordDefault"];
    }
```

**EDIT-2**

I do this as soon as i receive the response from server in my first view controller. I use these three data objects in sturtup but still it crashes

```
  NSUserDefaults *defaults=[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
            [defaults setObject:_username.text forKey:@"userNameDefault"];
            [defaults setObject:_password.text forKey:@"passwordDefault"];
            [defaults setObject:_server.text forKey:@"serverDefault"];
```

Comment: NSUserDefaults is the correct method. Show some code how you implement it.

Comment: @Darren can you please see my edit

Comment: Its not necessary to declare NSUser Defaults twice. Just use NSUserDefaults *defaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] then use [defaults setobject... For both. However that's not your problem. You say it crashes when you restart the app, what code is used on startup?

Comment: try [defaults synchronize].  That should force writing of the defaults to disk (I'm using the name suggested by @Darren -- you should do what he said too).

Comment: Yes I was just going to come back and add that. Put [defaults synchronize] at the end to force the defaults to be added.

Comment: username and password, also there is a third object used in startup. do i have to save all of them?

Comment: How are you getting uName and passWd into this class?  Have you checked to see that they are defined in this class?

Comment: Show us your startup code that retrieves the userdefaults

Comment: @rdelmar i initialized it from a different class(view controller).

Comment: @Darren sorry but i didn't retrieve Nsuserdefaults on startup

Comment: So your crash isn't to do with NSUserDefaults then. Are you trying to use uName and passWd before actually getting them back from user defaults? You need to use uName = [defaults objectForKey@"userNameDefault"] to get it back

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your setting the defaults again in your view controller when you want to be retrieving them to display them?
uName = [defaults objectForKey@"userNameDefault"]

Comment: no i dont set them again. I removed the first side from my class (but it still stays at the question). i have created all the methods, i use this informations to send a GET request to  my HTTP server, will i need to change those codes too?

Comment: Ok, You still haven't shown the code then for what's causing it to crash on startup. Which method crashes.

Comment: You use the 3 data objects on startup. Do you get the data objects back from NSUserDefaults using the method I posted before you try to use them?

Comment: I'm sorry but i really couldn't realize the scenerio. I can't understant why/from where it crashes. Excuse me if i disturb but i will ask a little situpidly; will i need to keep some track of restarting(for example, if the app has once started and gone to background, it shall bring its data from defaults..) How mus i design the lgorithm? Code is not such  a big deal, i can solve problems withe coding.. Thank

Comment: no i don't use that method to retrieve the data. I dont know where to use it

Comment: Well when your app starts, your uName object doesn't exist. You need to create it (alloc, init) then you need to retrieve the stored user default into it using the method above. NSUserDefaults works the same as storing to a file. You have to read it back in when you need it.

Comment: You could read the defaults in in your viewDidLoad or appDidLoad methods, but you'll need to check if they are nil for the first time it's run and they don't exist.

Comment: Thanks, the las comment gave me the idea.

Comment: Glad you got it. Don't forget to refresh the simulator and test it from a fresh install that won't have any user defaults set on first startup